# What is the need of filled ratio or load factor concept in HashSet

Tags: java, hashset

As I have studied HashSet class, it uses the concept of filled ratio, which says if the HashSet if filled up to this limit create a larger HashSet and copy values in to it. Why we dont let HashSet to get full with object and then create a new HashSet? Why a new concept is derived for HashSet?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3564638/hashset-load-factor?rq=1   does this help?

Comment: Can an `ArrayList` contain duplicates? Does an `ArrayList` use hash codes in any way? It's not a new concept - consider the `HashMap`.

Comment: @nullpointer no it does not help

Comment: @JonnyHenly I am just asking why to have this concept. There should be some need, right?

Comment: Well `ArrayLists` grow like how you've (somewhat wrongly) described how a `HashSet` grows. When a `HashSet` *grows* it increases its number of buckets by a power of two, then rehashes its entries into the buckets. When an `ArrayList` grows it creates a new underlying array at `1.5` times the size of the old array, it then copies the entries from the old array to the new array.

Comment: I didn't get what you are trying to say

Comment: I have edited my question please read it again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both ArrayList and Vector are accessed by positional index, so that there are no conflicts and access is always O(1).

A hash-based data structure is accessed by a hashed value, which can collide and degrade into access to a second-level "overflow" data structure (list or tree). If you have no such collisions, access is O(1), but if you have many collisions, it can be significantly worse. You can control this a bit by allocating more memory (so that there are more buckets and hopefully fewer collisions).

As a result, there is no need to grow an ArrayList to a capacity more than you need to store all elements, but it does make sense to "waste" a bit (or a lot) in the case of a HashSet. The parameter is exposed to allow the programmer to choose what works best for her application.

Answer (score 0):

As Jonny Henly has described. It is because of the way data is stored.

ArrayList is linear data structure, while HashSet is not. In HashSet data is stored in underlying array based on hashcodes. In a way performance of HashSet is linked to how many buckets are filled and how well data is distributed among these buckets. Once this distribution of data is beyond a certain level (called load factor) re-hashing is done.

Answer (score 0):

HashSet is primarily used to ensure that the basic operations (such as adding, fetching, modifying and deleting) are performed in constant time regardless of the number of entries being stored in the HashSet.

Though a well designed hash function can achieve this, designing one might take time. So if performance is a critical requirement for the application, we could use the load factor to ensure the operations are performed in constant time as well. I think we could call both of these as redundant's for each other (the load factor and the hash function).

I agree that this may not be a perfect explanation, but I hope it does bring some clarity on the subject.